# El pronombre de objeto directo en la oración "yo te llamo a ti" es obligatorio u opcional?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-directos

La oración

> Yo **te** llamo a ti

¿sería también correcta como

> Yo llamo a ti

sin "**te**"? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Precisamente has eliminado el único pronombre que no se podía eliminar en esa frase :) *Te llamo* es una frase perfectamente válida y tiene el mismo significado que la original; de hecho, a menos que queramos enfatizar alguno de los otros pronombres, lo más usual sería decirla así.

Comment: Es objeto directo, no objeto indirecto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, no sería correcto.

Cuando el pronombre se refiere a una persona, la norma dice que o bien se ponen ambos pronombre («***te***») y complemento («***a ti***»), o bien se pone solo el pronombre. Pero eliminar el pronombre en favor del complemento no es correcto.

[Referencia del DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF):

> **5.1.** Si el complemento tónico es también un pronombre personal, la coaparición del pronombre átono es obligatoria, tanto si el complemento es directo como indirecto: *Me castigaron a mí*; *A ti te dieron el premio* (no **Castigaron a mí*; **A ti dieron el premio*).