# Why do we say "preparó unos polvos que... les hacían llorar" and not "los hacían llorar"?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos, clíticos, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

I have come across this sentence in my textbook and I do not understand the choice of using the indirect pronoun. Could you explain it to me?

> preparó unos polvos que se les metían a los niños en los ojos y **les**
>   hacían llorar.

Edit: As far as I understood, the first *les* is correct and is the only variant we can use (no matter what part of the Spanish speaking world we are in). The first *les* repeats the *a los niños* part. As for the second *les*, there is no a unanimous grammar rule and it is not a mistake to put *los* here, right?

Comment: While you get a full answer try reading this about "leismo" http://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo.

Comment: @DGaleano thank you but it feels like I need to read the explanation in English so that nothing stays unclear.

Comment: i think the sentence  is incorrect or incomplete, "les" is the indirect object, to be correct we must add the missing object "les hacian llorar **sus ojos**" , i think "los" is the grammatically correct word connector.

Comment: @LoganXav I removed your new question, open a new one if you want. But first check if it's not already answered in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/what-is-the-role-of-the-le-in-the-sentence-miguel-le-dio-a-su-novia-un-anillo/2105 or https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21537/in-ella-les-cocina-a-ustedes-why-is-les-used-when-ustedes-is-used-later-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly hacer + infinitive constructions in spanish [can be very tricky syntactically speaking](http://www.gruposincom.es/manueliglesias/Pronombres%20hacer%20+%20infinitivo.pdf). And it is even trickier in this case because *llorar* is normally intransitive, but can be used as transitive.

Let's isolate the confusing sentence

> Unos polvos les hacían llorar

which semantically is the same as

> Unos polvos hacían llorar a los niños

I think 4.1 and ahead on the linked document addresses your question. There seems to be no consensus and some linguists accept one option (using *les* in this case), some accept the other (using *los*) and some accept both. 
The document quotes an author that says that if the verb is instransitive (like in this case), the trobulesome construction is direct object

> Cuando el verbo hacer se une con un verbo intransitivo, el sujeto de éste aparece en
>   la estructura superficial como objeto directo de la construcción entera: Juan hizo correr
>   a Pedro ---> Juan lo hizo correr, Hizo salir humo de la cocina --- > Lo hizo salir.
>   Unido a un verbo transitivo que lleve su propio complemento directo, el sujeto del infinitivo
>   puede aparecer representado como objeto indirecto del grupo: Juan hizo traer
>   un paquete a Pedro --- > Juan le hizo traer un paquete, Me hizo subir las escaleras,
>   Les hizo abrir las ventanas.

But others seem to think otherwise (from the same document)

> ... ) está el grave problema del leísmo, laísmo y loísmo, al efectuar tal prueba (la de
>   la conmutación). Y nos parece que S. Gutiérrez, al operar con la conmutación, ha
>   caído en esa trampa. Así, por ejemplo, admite indistintamente la conmutación por lo
>   o le en Dejó hablar al diputado (le/lo dejó hablar), sin percatarse del loísmo en el segundo
>   caso; y da por buena la conmutación de Hizo salir a su mujer --- > La hizo salir,
>   sin anotar el laísmo( ... ).

Edit:

> the first *les* is correct and is the only variant we can use

Yes. It repeats the indirect object (*los niños*), so it has to be *les* (or *le* if it was singular). By the way, the sentence is *pasiva refleja* (the direct object is turned into the subject and the verb is always preceded by *se*)

> As for the second les, there is no a unanimous grammar rule and it is not a mistake to put los here, right?

Yes. At least that was what I understood from searching around the Internet ,mainly the linked document.

Regarding *podemos dejarle los niños a mi madre si salimos*:

> Why dejarle? Does it relate to a mi madre?

Yes, it relates to *a mi madre*, which is indirect object.That is why you use *le* and not *la*.

> Shouldn't we repeat los niños by adding los to the verb?

It is not necessary. You can say:

- *podemos dejarle los niños a mi madre*
- *podemos dejarlos los niños a mi madre* (this one sounds weird, but I don't think it is syntactically incorrect)
- *podemos dejar los niños a mi madre* (no repeating)
- *podemos dejárselos los niños a mi madre* (repeating both, *se* is used instead of *le* or *les*)

Comment: Thank you for you patience and time. It feels like this part of the grammar is where I will often come back to.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are several complicating factors that might make the sentence more challenging.  Let's strip those away temporarily, to focus on the indirect pronoun, that you asked about.  Here's a simplified version:

> El doctor prepara unos polvos.  Se los mete a los niños en los ojos.  Los polvos les hacen llorar.

The third sentence says that the medications make them [the children] cry.  Why is the indirect pronoun *les* used instead of the direct pronoun *los*?  Well, actually, either one could be used, and I've learned on this site that there is some regional and personal variation that guides the choice.  I don't want to get into what's "correct." I will provide a rationale for the choice of indirect object, so you'll feel more comfortable with this when you see and hear it.

If you squeeze a lemon, juice will come out.  You squeeze the lemon, the lemon is the direct object of the squeezing.  If you make a child cry, the crying is an indirect result of whatever direct action you did.  Maybe you made a taunt, or threatened to cancel a birthday party, or applied a caustic medication to the child's eyes.  Directly, you said something or applied something, and those actions would affect a direct object.  The people affected by that action can be treated as an indirect object.